# Filter if value inside array exists has key in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

```
array = ['data', 'category', 'hour'];

    object = {
        "status": {
            "type": "INFO",
            "messages": []
        },
        "data": {
            "id": 1,
            "tenant": "675832",
            "process": "6911d872-35f8-11ea-8697-001dd8b71c20",
            "category": "resquests"
"time": {
hour: "12",
minute: "30"
        }
    }
```

I need to check if object has keys with same value contained in array.

I tried split array by dot, and then filter both array and object but it fails.

```
const array = inputValue.split('.').map((item) => item);
```

Comment: `const value = array.reduce((acc, p) => acc?.[p], object)`

Comment: Object.keys(object).filter(item => array.includes(item))

Answer (score -1):

Do you need something like that?

```
console.log(arrayEquals(Object.keys(object),array)
```

with

```
function arrayEquals(a, b) {
  return Array.isArray(a) &&
    Array.isArray(b) &&
    a.length === b.length &&
    a.every((val, index) => val === b[index]);
}
```